# Printf producing warnings when printing memory location yet still compiles and runs in xcode

Tags: c, xcode, pointers, printf

I'm new to C programming and am trying to work on pointers and arrays.  I have a rookie question I'd like to ask you all to help me understand.

I'm using Xcode to run a very simple C program that I'm writing.  To help me understand how this works I'm starting off with a very basic program and slowly build onto it to help learn. Here is my sample code:

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main(){

    int a[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    int *p = &a[0];

    printf("Address of first element of a = %d\n", p);
    printf("Number of elements in array = %lu\n", sizeof(a) / sizeof(int));

}
```

In Xcode, the first `printf` line produces a warning stating that "Format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'int *'.

I'd appreciate it if I can get some clarity as to why this is occurring and what is the proper way for me to code this?  This still compiles and running it produces the expect result.  So while the results may be correct, I personally need to understand what the fix for these warnings are.

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

using `""` is for when you create your own .h file

Moreover, p is pointer you have to derefenrence it `printf("Address of first element of a = %d\n", *p);`

Please, compile your .c file using flags `gcc -W -Wall -Wextra file.c`

**edit** : If you're looking to print the adress of the pointer and not the value of what it points to,  look out for the `%p` flag in printf : `printf("Address of first element of a = %p\n", p);`

Comment: Your first point I should have noticed.  Thanks!  But what I'm trying to do is to print up the memory address of the first index in the array.  That is where I'm experiencing this warning.  If I do print `*p` it only produces '1' which is the value of the first index and not the memory location.

Comment: @Pwrcdr87 look out to my edit. `%p` and not %d anymore

Comment: Yeah I noticed your update after I submitted my response.  Appreciate it much!  That did the job.  I have a reference for C 'printf' formats but didn't see `%p` in the list of available formats.  Thanks for that.  I found a list of codes that covers `%p` as well.  That's the fix and the answer.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You have declared p as a pointer to an int.  If you want to print the value it is pointing to (a[0], or 1, in this case), you need `*p`, not `p` as the parameter to printf()

Answer (score 0):

The `printf` format code for pointers is `%p`.  To print the address of the first element of the array, you should use `%p` instead of `%d`, and you must also cast the pointer to `void *`:

```
printf("Address of first element of a = %p\n", (void *)p);
```

On many computers (including, I think, all computers for which Xcode can generate executables), pointers are passed to variadic functions exactly the same way that some size of integer is, which is why you got the "expect result".  But it is still incorrect to print pointers with %d instead of %p, which is why Xcode complains.

(On nearly all computers, you can get away with leaving out the cast to `void *`, but it is still formally incorrect to do so.  It is treated with the same severity as any other kind of type mismatch between the `printf` format string and the arguments: *undefined behavior*, meaning that the program is allowed to work just fine but is also allowed to behave *arbitrarily wrong* - the stock joke is "the compiler is allowed to make demons fly out of your nose".)

Comment: Why do we must cast the pointer into (void *) if i do  `printf("adress : %p\n", p)` it will already print the adress no?

Comment: I'm interested in the response to @NicolasGuerin question as well.

Comment: I've tried to print the adress of `p` and `(void *)p` and they are the same. So you don't need to cast into `(void *)` as soon as it is already a pointer.

Comment: Yes you do need the cast, even though it's already a pointer and even though it appears to work on your computer.  If you don't have the cast, you have "undefined behavior", which means you can get away with it on some computers but on others demons will fly out of your nose.  I'm not kidding about the demons.